# Why does a div with a height of 70px measure 103x in a graphics program?

Tags: css

Browser is at default zoom level, screen is 1920*1200.

Take a screenshot of the fiddle and measure the height of the div in fireworks or gimp and it gives 103px. Why?

CSS:

```
#test {
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 70px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pmfy2e35/.

Comment: I didn't get. It's equal to 70px

Comment: works for me to. measuring is 70px

Comment: Because images aren't web pages?

Comment: what about dpi scaling settings in your browser? for example firefox has `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` and is -1.0 for me

Comment: What led you to grab a screenshot and use a graphics program to measure the element in the first place?

Comment: sure you don't have any zoom switched on? tried [ctrl] + [0]?

Answer (score 0):

I measured it with a Google Chrome extension named "Page Ruler" and it's height is exactly 70px + 2px for the border (top + bottom). Page Ruler measures the height directly in the browser, I use it a lot for developing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I right clicked the box and selected "Inspect Element". Then in developer tools I can see it's height is 70px.